# How to retrieve the class type via reflection of return object?

Tags: java, reflection

I want generalize some code but stuck on a problem which i think to be solved with reflection.

In my service methods I convert from dto to entity and vice versa. So I have in each service class a method like this

```
private LicenseDTO convertToDto(LicenseEntity entity) {
    LicenseDTO dto = modelMapper.map(entity, LicenseDTO.class);
    return dto;
}
```

To reduce duplication I moved this to an abstract class and there i want to genrealize this. S is my entity class an T my dto. The modelmapper requires the class type of S but how can I extract this via reflection?

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected S convertToEntity(T dto){

    Class<S> typeOfS = null;
    typeOfS = (Class<S>) getClass();
    Method[] methods = typeOfS.getDeclaredMethods();


    return modelMapper.map(dto, typeOfS);
}
```

Comment: From inside the method itself? You can't.

Comment: Why not take it as a parameter? `S convertToEntity(Class<S> entityClass, T dto)`?

Comment: What duplication are you trying to reduce? The `LicenseDTO` name? Then skip the local variable: `return modelMapper.map(entity, LicenseDTO.class);`. You still need to specify the object to convert (`entity`) and the target type (`LicenseDTO.class`), nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @Andreas the duplication occurs in the service classes, for every use case i have one and in each i needed to implement these convert methods now I declared it in once place

Comment: suggested I have solved it by using a second parameter as  @ernest_k suggested

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see any reduction in duplication between `return modelMapper.map(entity, LicenseDTO.class);` and `return convertToEntity(entity, LicenseDTO.class);`

Comment: @Andreas This is not the reduction which I meant. I have a few service classes and before my refactoring each of those had to implement this method. Now with extracting this method into an abstract class this is not necessary anymore, so this reduces the code inside my service classes.